# Sonatype Nexus only starting in console mode

Tags: nexus

I installed Nexus 3.6.0-02 on Redhat 7.4.

I am able to get Nexus to start in console mode by running the command: ./nexus run

If I try and start nexus as a service per the following documentation, nothing happens.

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Run+as+a+Service

If I run the command ./nexus start, the application does not start and there is nothing written into any nexus logs indicating why it failed to start.

The install and sonatype-work directories are all owned by the user who I have configured Nexus to run as.

Any ideas as to where to look or troubleshoot to figure this problem out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am using nexus 3 . I resolved this by deleting lock file placed inside nexus3 folder of sonatype folder and restart it by nexus start command.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "run_as_user" configured in $install_dir/bin/nexus.rc has permissions to write to the installation directory and the work directory.  And make sure they have a login shell, that is required for the startup script to work.